# Java on Oracle 10g R2

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

We have Java code developed in Oracle DB 11G or java 1.5, ( we Execute Java from plsql)
Recently we came across a Legacy Oracle Database system 10G R2(10.2.0.4.0) Unix-OS. It has Java 1.4 only. Most of our Java code is not working on 10G R2.
What steps need to be taken to run Java 1.5 (old) code on 10G R2 .

Comment: You can't - you need to migrate ( = change) the code so it is 1.4 compatible. Java 5 (less popularly known as Java 1.5) added many new language features which will never compile on Java 1.4.

Comment: Just to add to @Gimby's comment, the JVM that runs inside the database cannot be upgraded, it's integrated with the database engine.  You can't upgrade a 10.2 database's JVM to Java 5.  You could install a Java 1.5 JVM outside the database (on the same server potentially) but that may be as big an architecture change as updating the code to support Java 1.4.

Comment: Upgrading the database to 11g is probably the most cost effective in the end, if you ask me.

Comment: Finally we decided to Downgrade our Java 1.5 code to Java 1.4. Any suggestions, How to proceed with automation?